# How do I set a random number within a shared data variable in different class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get a random number generated within the text entry box. It is not working since I'm not sure how to share the variable. I am using python tkinter in visual studio code if that helps. The variable receipt_no is supposed to generate a random number between 1000-9999 in a text entry box. I get an error which is 'str' object has no attribute 'set'.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  
        self.shared_data = {"receipt_no":tk.IntVar,
                            "receipt.no":tk.IntVar,
                            "receipt.no".set(str(random.randint(1000,9999))):tk.IntVar}

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage,RandomPage):
                  
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")
    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''

        frame.tkraise()       

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='#3d3d5c')
        self.controller = controller

        def next():
           controller.show_frame('RandomPage')

        next_button = tk.Button(text='Next',
                                command=next,
                                relief='raised',
                                borderwidth=3,
                                width=18,
                                height=2)
        next_button.place(x=1090, y=475)                  

class RandomPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='#3d3d5c')
        self.controller = controller

        order_number = tk.Label(self,
                         text="Customer order number",
                         font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
                         foreground='#ffffff',
                         background='#33334d')
        order_number.place(anchor=tk.N, bordermode=tk.INSIDE, x=200, y=500) 
                 
        order_number_entry =tk.Entry(self,
                                      width=12,
                                      font=('Arial 20'),
                                      textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["receipt_no"])  
        order_number_entry.place(anchor=tk.N, bordermode=tk.INSIDE, x=500, y=500)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

I have tried to set the value and try share it to a different class. I am expecting to get a random generated number between 1000-9999.

Comment: Where is entry point in your code for the number and with which part is it supposed to be shared? please specify it in your question.

Comment: So the variable receipt.no is the entry point I guess and is supposed to be shared. I'm trying to get that variable to generate a random number between 1000-9999.

Comment: Change `self.shared_data = {...}` to `self.shared_data = {"receipt_no":tk.IntVar(value=random.randint(1000, 9999))}`.

Comment: That also works. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating a dictionary to get the `receipt_no` value to set the text of Entry widget with, don't generate its value using .set, just create one `tk.IntVar()` variable and one `string` variable to store the random number.

```
self.shared_data = {"receipt_no":tk.IntVar(),
                    "random_receipt_no":str(random.randint(1000,9999))}
```

Now, to set the text of Entry widgets, you might want to use `insert` method:

```
order_number_entry =tk.Entry(self,
                             width=12,
                             font=('Arial 20'), 
                             textvariable = self.controller.shared_data["receipt_no"])
order_number_entry.insert(0,self.controller.shared_data["random_receipt_no"])
```